# Extract slug from unsplash

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a list of photos, fetched from this url https://picsum.photos/v2/list.
In this list there is slug that should be extracted, for example https://unsplash.com/photos/_h7aBovKia4.
Here is fetch thing I used

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import ImageList from "./ImageList";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      images: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://picsum.photos/v2/list")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ images: data });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error happened during fetching!', err);
        });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h2 className="title">Images list</h2>
            <ImageList data={this.state.images}/>
        </div>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And here is ImageList Component

```js
import React from "react";
import Image from "./Image";

const ImageList = props => {
    const results = props.data;
    let images = results.map(image => <Image url={image.url} key={image.id}/>);

    return (
        <ul className="img-list">{images}</ul>
    );
};

export default ImageList;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

How can I get that slug from each photo url? without it, images aren't showing in browser, just their alts

UPD. Image Component

```js
import React from "react";

const Image = props => {
    return (
        <li className="image-wrap">
            <img src={props.url} alt="Something went wrong"/>
        </li>
    )
}


export default Image;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The snippets don't work, unfortunately. Could you fix them?

Comment: can you show us your "Image" component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `download_url` property, not `url`.

The `url` points to a Unsplash page with comments, site interface etc. The `download_url` however is a direct link to the image.

[image]